# Shuffle questions which are in an Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, shuffle

I created three Arrays: Question Array, Choices Array, Answers Array in another java class. Now I want that theese questions will shuffle random when a Choice (Wrong or False) will be pressed My codes are first the QuestionLibrary, next the main activity.

```
package amapps.impossiblequiz;

public class QuestionLibrary {





    private String mQuestions[] = {
            "When was the European Union founded?",
            "How many Grad Celsius is one Kelvin?",
            "What is THC?",
            "How many legs has a spider?",
            "How many stars has the European flag?",
            "Which is the seventh planet from the sun?",
            "What is the chemical formula of salt?",
            "Who said: Ich bin ein berliner?",
            "To which country belongs Greenland?",
            "What is the result of: 2 + 2 *5?",
            "How many mountains are higher than 8000 meter/26.246 ft?",
            "A famous quote is: to be, or____ to be!",
            "What is the name of Stalingrad nowadays?"

    };

    private String mChoices[][] = {
            {"1993", "1986", "1967"},
            {"-260", "-272,15", "279,15"},
            {"a plant","The active substance of marijuana" , "a spider"},
            {"6", "10","8"},
            {"12","15","10"},
            {"Uranus","Neptune","Saturn"},
            {"HCl","NaCl","CO"},
            {"John F. Kennedy", "Richard Nixon","James A. Garfield"},
            {"Canada","Denmark", "Greenland is an own state?"},
            {"12","20","14"},
            {"10","12","14"},
            {"not","never","now"},
            {"Leningrad","Wolgograd","Dimitrijgrad"}
    };


    private String mCorrectAnswers[] = {"1993", "-272,15", "The active substance of marijuana", "8", "12","Uranus","NaCl","John F. Kennedy","Denmark","12","14","not","Wolgograd"};



    public String getQuestion (int a){
        String question = mQuestions[a];
        return question;
    }

    public String getChoice1 (int a){
        String choice0 = mChoices[a][0];
        return choice0;
}

    public String getChoice2 (int a) {
        String choice1 = mChoices[a][1];
        return choice1;
    }

    public String getChoice3 (int a) {
        String choice2 = mChoices [a] [2];
        return choice2;
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer (int a){
        String answer = mCorrectAnswers [a];
        return answer;


    }



}
```

if correct= random question from array/If false too

```
        mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();

                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong... Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mScore = 0;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();

                }
            }


        });
```

Now i tried a new code to shuffle my array, but all s full of errors....

package amapps.impossiblequiz;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Question {

```
    private String question;
    private String[] choices;
    private String answer;

    public Question(String question, String[] choices, String answer) {
        super();
        this.question = question;
        this.choices = choices;
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public String[] getChoices() {
        return choices;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

}

//create list
List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();

//add one question
questions.add(
        new Question(
                "What's you name?",
                        new String[]{"Foo","Bar","John","Doe"},
        "Bar"
        )
        );

//add another question
questions.add(
        new Question(
                "What's you name?",
                        new String[]{"Foo","Bar","John","Doe"},
        "Bar"
        )
        );

//shuffle questions
Collections.shuffle(questions);





public int getlength() {


    int length = 13;
    return length;
}
```

}

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: That didn`t help me nothing, please tell me what to write in my code sir!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to keep your questions and answers in separate arrays, as you won't be able to reconnect them one you shuffled you arrays. 
I'd recommend to write a `Question` class like so:

```
public class Question {

    private String question;
    private String[] choices;
    private String answer;

    public Question(String question, String[] choices, String answer) {
        super();
        this.question = question;
        this.choices = choices;
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public String[] getChoices() {
        return choices;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

}
```

and then use a List to manage the questions:

```
    //create list
    List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();

    //add one question
    questions.add(
            new Question(
                    "What's you name?",
                    new String[]{"Foo","Bar","John","Doe"},
                    "Bar"
            )
    );

    //add another question
    questions.add(
            new Question(
                    "What's you name?",
                    new String[]{"Foo","Bar","John","Doe"},
                    "Bar"
            )
    );

    //shuffle questions
    Collections.shuffle(questions);
```

EDIT: Of course there is a lot to improve about this Questions class - for example it would be better to have a `.addChoice(String choice)` method instead of having to pass an array of strings to the constructor. But that's up to you :)

Comment: Some tips - you could omit the `super()` in the Question constructor, and use the diamond operator `List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: I will definitely test this one, will I have to change something in my main activity?

Comment: Can not resolve add, can not resolve simbol shuffle? What should I do`?

Comment: @ProjectX The second code block is supposed to be inside a method (main method or some other, not inside a class body directly). `add()` is a method of the ArrayList, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The (awesome) way: personally implement the **Fisher-Yates** shuffle. It's really only a few lines of code:

```
// mutates original array
  private static <T> void shuffle(T[] arr){
    Random r = new Random();
    // iterates back to front
    for(int i=arr.length-1; i>0; i--){
      // swap
      int k = r.nextInt(i);
      T tmp = arr[k];
      arr[k] = arr[i];
      arr[i] = tmp;
    }
  }
```

The easy way:
`Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(mQuestions));`

Comment: Hello frozen should i insert this in my question library?

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList instead and do this:

```
Collections.shuffle(yourArrayListName);
```